# How to get all email in thunderbird not just new ones?

Tags: email, thunderbird, pop3

Is it possible to get all emails in thunderbird even already read messages like how it works in MS Outlook? Right now it just gets new ones if I read emails using another client or using my phone they won't get fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting all messages in Thunderbird is the default.

Did you accidentily click on the buttton [Unread] above the mails? That would cause it to download all mail but only display the unread ones.

Comment: Not really, I don't have any filters on :(

Comment: Is the other client using pop3 without 'leave a copy of the mail on the server' ticked?